# Google Login from flutterfire_ui works only in Beta channel release, not in production release

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

**Clicking on "Sign in with Google" button has no effect.**

**Technical details:-**

- Firebase hosting is used
- flutterfire_ui package is used (v0.3.0)
- Added the appropriate **Authorised JavaScript origins** and **Authorised redirect URIs** at Google Cloud Platform -> APIs and Services -> Credentials
- Added the Google web app Client ID in my Flutter app
- In my Firebase hosting, I have a custom domain as well. Default domain is: my-app.firebaseapp.com and my custom domain is: my-custom.domain.co
- Everything works fine with Beta release (flutter build web and then firebase hosting:channel:deploy my-test-release)
  **- Google login works fine at my default domain, but not at my custom domain.**
- Added all the appropriate **Authorised JavaScript origins** and **Authorised redirect URIs** at Google Cloud Platform -> APIs and Services -> Credentials for both the domains: default and custom domains.
- Flutter: Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
  Framework • revision 77d935af4d (3 weeks ago) • 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
  Engine • revision 890a5fca2e
  Tools • Dart 2.15.1
- npm : 8.1.2
- node: v16.13.1
- MacOS: 12.1
- Browsers: CHROME,SAFARI on desktop and mobile as well.
- firebase: ^9.0.2 (in pubspec.yaml)
- google_sign_in: ^5.2.1 (in pubspec.yaml)
- firebase_auth: ^3.3.3 (in pubspec.yaml)
- Implemented Auth screen as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder<User?>(
stream:  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()
builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         return SignInScreen(
           showAuthActionSwitch: false,
           actions: [
             AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, _) {
                  // whenever auth state changes to SignedIn 
                  // Do some operations and then navigate to some screen
                   Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                   Routes.createChart, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
             }),
           ]
            providerConfigs: const [
             GoogleProviderConfiguration(
               clientId:
                   'my-app-google-web-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
             ),
           ],
         );
       } // end if
      
     return const MyHomePage(title: StringConstants.appTitle);
)
```

**Observation**

- Clicking on "Sign in with Google" has no effect

**Expected behaviour**

- Clicking on "Sign in with Google" button should open a popup or a new tab in the browser, and user should be able to login with one of his Google account credentials.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.