# Flutter app (stable channel) as of January 2022, google sign-in using flutterfire_ui does not work

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_ui/example

We run the above sample code to see the behavior.

I was able to authenticate with email password, but I cannot sign in with Google authentication. (The screen after sign-in is not displayed.)

pubspec.yaml(Relevant parts)

```
  firebase_core: ^1.11.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.5
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.6
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.3
  flutterfire_ui: ^0.3.1
```

---

Message displayed at runtime

```
D/libMEOW (17066): applied 1 plugins for [com.example.fbnew]:
D/libMEOW (17066):   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
V/PhoneWindow(17066): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@95dc476[]
D/ViewRootImpl[SignInHubActivity](17066): hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/InputTransport(17066): Create ARC handle: 0xb400006e60644590
V/PhoneWindow(17066): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@cdc916f, this = DecorView@95dc476[SignInHubActivity]
I/OpenGLRenderer(17066): 
I/OpenGLRenderer(17066): --xw 3gap: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer(17066): 
I/chatty  (17066): uid=10376(com.example.fbnew) RenderThread identical 1 line
I/OpenGLRenderer(17066): 
V/PhoneWindow(17066): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@619d719, this = DecorView@ee063de[MainActivity]
V/PhoneWindow(17066): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@cdc916f, this = DecorView@95dc476[SignInHubActivity]
D/View    (17066): [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@95dc476[SignInHubActivity]
I/InputTransport(17066): Destroy ARC handle: 0xb400006e60644590
I/OpenGLRenderer(17066): 
I/chatty  (17066): uid=10376(com.example.fbnew) RenderThread identical 3 lines
I/OpenGLRenderer(17066):
```

---

[Google Login from flutterfire_ui works only in Beta channel release, not in production release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616668/google-login-from-flutterfire-ui-works-only-in-beta-channel-release-not-in-prod)

The above question has been posted, but in the end, is it not possible to use google sign-in with flutterfire_ui at this time?

I can't find any such explanation in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting (copying and pasting) the "debug" SHA1 certificate fingerprint in the project, I was able to sign in to Google.

I had already released this app, so I had set the SHA1 certificate fingerprint for "release", but when I debugged it, I had to set the one for "debug".